# How to find a max value of a specific key in a dictionary in a list in a document in mongodb?

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to use an aggregation to get the highest value of a specified key that's in a dict field that's in a list field that's in a document that's in a mongodb collection.

Here's some example data

```
[
  {
    "name": "hi",
    "hist": [
      {
        "username": "bill",
      },
      {
        "username": "jack",
        "changed_from": 127
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "member1",
    "hist": [
      {
        "username": "asdf",
        "changed_from": 123
      },
      {
        "username": "duhby",
        "changed_from": 126
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "member5",
    "hist": [
      {
        "username": "duhby",
        "changed_from": 150
      },
      {
        "username": "test",
        "changed_from": 123
      },
      {
        "username": "duhby",
        "changed_from": 125
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to be able to put in `duhby` as the username, for example, and get at least a list of results I can then easily get the maximum value of, with the maximum value in this case being `150`.

I tried using an aggregate group but got stuck when trying to only get the data from the specific username, and not just all documents that had that username in the `hist` field.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": "$hist.duhby",
      update_time: {
        $max: "$hist.changed_from"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

With the example data shown earlier, this returns:

```
[
  {
    "_id": [],
    "update_time": [
      150,
      123,
      125
    ]
  }
]
```

However, this isn't useful because it shows every `changed_from` value when I want it to only show (and sort by) the ones with the username specified. Expected result:

```
[
  {
    "_id": [],
    "update_time": [
      150,
      125
    ]
  }
]
```

I also want to be able to get the original document and maybe have the `name` field as the id in the aggregation, but the id is currently returned as an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

I realized here that what I needed is just a find, not an aggregation, because I was just trying to see if any document existed that had the embedded document with a key value pair of a certain value. The following does what I was looking for:

```
db.collection.find({
  "hist": {
    $elemMatch: {
      username: "duhby",
      changed_from: {
        "$lte": 123
      }
    }
  }
})
```